# Assigning stack variable to malloc'd memory inside a loop changes data in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

So I have this function that dynamically allocates a buffer large enough to hold a string of any length from a text file (`fgetLine`). I am using this function inside a loop to process a text file line by line. 
I want to store different fields from each line in the text file inside a circular linked list, however, it seems that the line being returned by my dynamic allocation function keeps getting overwritten and so only the very last entry of the file is getting stored inside the linked list. How do I fix this?

I have looked at this using gdb and my circular linked list implementation works fine, but I don't understand why updating the variable `line` keeps changing the values stored in the stack struct `scale` from the loops the previous iteration even after moving to a different node inside the linked list. That is, the `scale.name` stored in a previous node gets changed based on the current loops iteration and whatever has been assigned to `line`. I thought maybe I should be freeing `line` between iterations but this only prevents anything from being stored in the nodes. Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "List.h"

#define DATA(L) ((L)->data)
#define NEXT(L) ((L)->next)
#define BACK(L) ((L)->back)

typedef struct node_t {
    void          *data;
    struct node_t *back;
    struct node_t *next;
} node_t;

char*
fgetLine(FILE *stream);

struct scale_t {
    char *name;
    char *intervals;
};

int
main(int argc,
     char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    node_t *head = List_createnode(NULL);

    /*** TROUBLE AREA ***/
    for (char *line; (line = fgetLine(fp));) {
        struct scale_t scale;
        scale.name = strtok(line, ",\t");
        scale.intervals = strtok(NULL, ",\040\t");
        List_prepend(head, &scale);
    }

    node_t *cur = NEXT(head);
    while (DATA(cur)) {
        puts((*((struct scale_t *)DATA(cur))).name);
        cur = NEXT(cur);
    }
}

char*
fgetLine(FILE *stream)
{
    const size_t chunk = 128;
    size_t max = chunk;

    /* Preliminary check */
    if (!stream || feof(stream))
        return NULL;

    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(chunk * sizeof(char));
    if (!buffer) {
        perror("Unable to allocate space");
        return NULL;
    }
    char *ptr = buffer;
    for (; (*ptr = fgetc(stream)) != EOF && *ptr != '\n'; ++ptr) {

        size_t offset = ptr - buffer;
        if (offset >= max) {
            max += chunk;

            char *tmp = realloc(buffer, max);
            if (!tmp) {
                free(buffer);
                return NULL;
            }
            buffer = tmp;
            ptr = tmp + offset;
        }
    }
    *ptr = '\0';
    return buffer;
}
```

```
/* in List.h */
typedef enum { OK,    ERROR } status_t;
typedef enum { FALSE, TRUE  } bool;

node_t*
List_createnode(void *Data)
{
    node_t *node_new = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if (!node_new) {
        perror("Unable to allocate node_t.");
        return NULL;
    }
    DATA(node_new) = Data;

    /* Leave this assignment to other functions. */
    NEXT(node_new) = NULL;
    BACK(node_new) = NULL;

    return node_new;
}

status_t
List_prepend(node_t *next,
             void   *data)
{
    if (!next)
        return ERROR;

    node_t *node_new = List_createnode(data);
    if (!node_new) {
        perror("Unable to allocate node_t.");
        return ERROR;
    }
    DATA(node_new) = data;
    NEXT(node_new) = next;

    /* If BACK(next) is NULL then 'next' node_t is the only node in the list. */
    if (!BACK(next)) {
        BACK(node_new) = next;
        NEXT(next) = node_new;
    } else {
        /* When BACK(next) is not NULL store this into BACK(node_new).. */
        BACK(node_new) = BACK(next);

        /* Prepending to 'next' node is same as appending to the node originally
         * pointed to by BACK(next). */
        NEXT(BACK(next)) = node_new;
    }
    /* Now update BACK(next) to point to the new prepended node. */
    BACK(next) = node_new;
    return OK;
}
```

Comment: You probably want `scale.name = strtok(line, ",\t"); scale.intervals = strtok(NULL, ",\040\t");` It would be helpful if you could _edit_ your code block and include `List_prepend`. This would help us look for potential memory leaks.

Comment: Note that `(*ptr = fgetc(stream)) != EOF` is testing a `char` value to be `EOF` whereas `fgetc` returns an `int` value, so be wary of this. Your loop control statements are ambitious.

Comment: You only reallocate the buffer *after* you have written past its length. Also when writing the final `*ptr = '\0';` you don't check if there is enough buffer allocation.

Comment: @CraigEstey sorry I didn't realize I left that. I had what you have originally but still had the problem. I'll update it. Also what do you mean by "you could edit your code block"? also I'll add in `List_prepend` to end of file.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah! failed to notice that, would it fix to cast `((unsigned char)*ptr = fgetc(stream)) != EOF`?

Comment: No, `EOF` is typically `-1`. It would be better to simplify the loop control to read the value from `fgetc` into an `int`, and then write it into the buffer ***after*** you check its size.

Comment: @skyfire Casts aren't lvalues, so that wouldn't compile. If you assign the result of `fgetc` to a (signed) `char` and compare it to `EOF`, you're going to misinterpret a valid byte (a letter even, in ISO 8859-1) as end-of-file. If you assign it to an `unsigned char` and compare it to `EOF`, it will never return true, so you get an infinite loop.

Comment: @WeatherVane believe I have fixed the reallocate part you mentioned.

Comment: Please don't "fix" the code in the question, add as an edit if you need to. Otherwise people won't follow the comments. And you haven't fixed it, but made the `for` loop control even more bizarre. You still write to past the buffer end when full. Rolled back.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm having a hard time finding where Im writing past the buffer. If I move my `++ptr` to the first line of the `for` body the `offset >= max` should detect whether I have filled the buffer. If I have not filled the buffer and the `for` condition test occurs again and `EOF` appears then the `for` is exited and `*ptr = '\0'` would overwrite `EOF`.

Comment: You write past the end of the buffer in the `for` loop control with `*ptr = fgetc(stream)` and this is *before* you test if there is buffer overflow. If the offset is `max` then effectively you write to `ptr[max]` which breaks the allocation. You may only write to `ptr[max-1]`, as with an array of `max` elements .

Comment: Add `List_createnode` as well. The reason is that if it does _not_ do a `node->data = malloc(sizeof(struct scale_t)); memcpy(node->data,data,sizeof(struct scale_t));` then there is another problem. Otherwise, in `main`, you'd need: `struct scale_t *scale = malloc(sizeof(struct scale_t)); scale->name = strtok(line, ",\t"); scale->intervals = strtok(NULL, ",\040\t"); List_prepend(head, scale);` This is because, as you have it, `scale` is _loop_ scoped and all prepended nodes will point to `scale` at the _same_ address if _somebody_ doesn't duplicate it with a `malloc`

Comment: @WeatherVane But the `offset >= max` occurs right after `ptr++`. Which means the for conditional using `ptr` was satisfied, which in turn means `ptr++` may occur and `offset >= max` catches whether or not `ptr++` increased up to `buffer` size yet.

Comment: Yes, but `*ptr = fgetc(stream)` occurs right before it. The second part of a `for` statement is evaluated at the *start* of each loop, and the third part at the end of the loop. Perhaps your fix did work, but it is a horrible way of writing the loop and hard to follow.

Comment: @CraigEstey just a moment, I will add shortley

Comment: @WeatherVane This should not matter, the address of `(ptr + 1)` is checked before the next iteration(assuming we move `ptr++` to the very first line of the loop body). So I am guessing you are meaning the very first iteration? `char *ptr = buffer;` occurs before the first loop test and if the very first test fails `ptr++` is not triggered in the loop body and so `*ptr = '\0'` may be written.

Comment: Okay, from your `List_creatnode`, it does _not_ do `malloc` for `data` _and_ doesn't know the length. So, _caller_ (i.e. `main`) must do the `malloc` for `struct scale_t`. So, change `main` according to my previous comment. The list functions don't care _what_ `data` points to (hence the `void *` pointer), but the callers (e.g. `main`) do, so they have to ensure the `data` argument they pass has been allocated uniquely

Comment: @CraigEstey - that's the write-up for the `/***TROUBLE AREA***/`. It warrants a separate answer. Will leave that to you since your comments are essentially the crux of the answer.

Comment: @skyfire - is there any particular reason you have not posted [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You are likely to get additional help, and perhaps even some undiscovered issues fixed if you post something that can be compiled. That helps us help you with your question (and likely the primary reason for the DV). Following the rules in [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and providing a MCVE will avoid all but the most cynical downvotes.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I thought it best to post the minimal amount of code to get my point across, but if you want--I am willing to set up a github gist for exactly that and could link it here.

Comment: As @CraigEstey, mentions in his answer, ultimately "enough" code was posted to allow an accurate answer, but what you posted still cannot be compiled. That is the "C - Complete" part of MCVE. Since you have an answer now, no need to post additional code now, but in the future, always work to provide code that can be compiled (including the `#include` statements, etc...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin will do, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is prefaced by my top comments.

Now that enough code has been posted ...

The key issue is that, in `main`, `scale` is *loop* scoped (i.e. *not* heap allocated)

So even though `fgetLine` returns a `malloc`ed buffer, and the results of the `strtok` calls point *within* that buffer, the address of `scale` passed to `List_prepend` will be the *same* address on each iteration in `main`.

`List_prepend` does *not* `malloc` and `memcpy` its `data` argument (and doesn't know the length it would need to use), so a *caller* of `List_prepend` must do this.

Thus, we must fix this in `main` by changing:

```
for (char *line; (line = fgetLine(fp));) {
    struct scale_t scale;

    scale.name = strtok(line, ",\t");
    scale.intervals = strtok(NULL, ",\040\t");

    List_prepend(head, &scale);
}
```

Into:

```
for (char *line; (line = fgetLine(fp));) {
    struct scale_t *scale = malloc(sizeof(struct scale_t));

    scale->name = strtok(line, ",\t");
    scale->intervals = strtok(NULL, ",\040\t");

    List_prepend(head, scale);
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> is there a name for the phenomena wherein "the address of scale passed to List_prepend will be the same address on each iteration in main."? I had thought being in loop scope would mean a new scale would be created each time and I could transfer these temporary values onto List_prepend.

Loop scope and function scope variables end up in the function stack frame. It might be easier to see why it *doesn't* work if you moved `struct scale_t scale;` to function scope.

Loop scope *may* do a little finagling with the stack pointer [or may *not*]. It *could* just compile the code as if the definition were function scoped.

Or, it might do this:

At the loop top, the stack pointer is decremented by `sizeof(struct stack_t)` [with appropriate alignment].

Then, `scale` gets that address. This gets passed to `List_prepend`.

At the bottom of the loop, `scale` will "go out of scope", so the stack pointer is incremented by `sizeof(struct stack_t)`.

Now, the stack pointer has its original value again. The one it had at the top of the previous loop iteration.

Lather, rinse, repeat ...

An optimizing compiler *could* see that doing the decrement/increment sequence *inside* the loop is wasteful. It could move the decrement *above* the loop and the increment *after* the loop, achieving the same effect.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it. Really quick though, is there a name for the phenomena wherein "the address of `scale` passed to `List_prepend` will be the same address on each iteration in main."? I had thought being in loop scope would mean a new `scale` would be created each time and I could transfer these temporary values onto `List_prepend`. Just wanna try and avoid future headaches if possible.

Comment: The issue is you are assigning the address of a locally declared variable. There is no guarantee that every iteration will have the same address, but it is very highly likely. When your `for` loop completes, all variables local to the loop are released for re-use. Since nothing else is happening between the completion of each iteration, the variables will likely have the same address as they did last time because nothing else has altered the stack in between the completion of one iteration and the start of the next.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Ah! I see, you are referring to `List_prepend(head, &scale);` part (and the fact that `scale` was a local variable). So the fix was to move the memory to heap using `malloc`. Will freeing be as simple as `free(head->data)`? (assuming `head` is some `node_t` I am interested in reusing or deleting)

Comment: Yep, you got it. That is one of the most common areas where new C programmers get bit when working with lists, etc... When working with data for each node, you must ensure that the address held by each node is unique. The most common way to do that is to allocate storage for each node and for each pointer member of each node. (each non-pointer member of the node with *automatic storage duration* already has a unique address)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin _Side note:_ David, I just looked at your profile. It seems different. Just curious: Did you just start your own firm?

Comment: @CraigEstey - yes, back in 1999, then went into a partnership what fell apart in 2005, and have basically been on my own since then. No recent change though (except google listing me as out of business because I block 50% of the IP ranges `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You are writing past the end of the buffer allocation when it is full, because you write data to it before you make the size check. I suggest using a `while` loop like this:

```
char *ptr = buffer;
int ch;                                 // int not char
while((ch = fgetc(stream)) != EOF && ch != '\n') {

    size_t offset = ptr - buffer;
    if (offset >= max - 1) {            // allow room for terminator
        max += chunk;

        char *tmp = realloc(buffer, max);
        if (!tmp) {
            free(buffer);
            return NULL;
        }
        buffer = tmp;
        ptr = tmp + offset;
    }
    *ptr++ = ch;                       // now write to buffer
}
*ptr = '\0';
```